# How to convert an already made string(with single-quote) to a double-quotes string (so could act on escape sequences)

Tags: php, string, forms, post

I am trying to read the data with $_POST which has been sent through a form. the form sends the data in octal format. this is part of the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="chap-challenge" value="\314\130\024\000\350\025"
```

the problem is that,

```
echo $_POST['chap-challenge'];
```

would give me the literal string:

```
\314\135\024\000\354\025
```

which is not the same as

```
echo "\314\135\024\000\354\025";
```

how can i somehow convert that string to a double-quoted one so that it could understand they are octal values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can evaluate it as php expression, but it lacks in security - [example](http://ideone.com/ssU1Q).

```
<?php
echo "\100\101\102\103\104\n";

$c = '\100\101\102\103\104';
eval( '$c2="'.$c.'";' );

echo $c,"\n";
echo $c2;
```

### Edit:

Also you can parse it for your own - [example](http://ideone.com/NOikL):

```
<?
echo "\100\101\102\103\104\n";

$c = '\100\101\102\103\104';
$c2 = explode('\\',$c);
$c3 = array();
$c4 = array();
foreach($c2 as $cc) {
   $c3[] = octdec($cc);
   $c4[] = chr(octdec($cc));
}
$c4 = implode('',$c4);

echo $c,"\n";
var_dump($c3);
var_dump($c4);
```

### Edit:

To remove first item from array use: [array_shift function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php).

Comment: both solutions are really interesting. thank you for sharing them. eval indeed lacks in security, specially if part of the expression comes directly from $_POST. but the latest example is just perfect :) . i really appreciate the help. thank you again

Comment: Just a little side note, if you notice the var_dump($c3)/var_dump($c4) results, they have one more character than the original string. $c3[0] is int(0). although you cant see that but should be noted if you need to do some hashing on the string later on.

Comment: Yes it certainly does. thank you again. i appropriate it :) i made a function out of it and in the last line, i used return(substr($c4,1)); to remove the first character of the string

Comment: This will work only if you only have octals, but regular chars will mess it up.

Answer (score 2):

`$_POST` does not use any quotes for it's strings. It just does not evaluate them. Quotes are for programmer. You'll need to process this string a little, then feed it into [`base_convert()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php) function

Comment: Its interesting to know that Quotes are only for programmer. ive never looked at it that way. thanks for clarification

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can solve the problem by storing the html entities of those characters, or using PHP to generate them.

```
 <input name="chap-challenge" value='<?php echo "\100\130\024\000\350\025" ?>
```

$_POST['chap-challenge'] will now begin with `%40`, which is translated by PHP as `@`, etc.

---

To actually answer your question, though:
Any string passed to MySQL, even if it had been single quoted, is treated and stored as though it had been double-quoted and evaluated.

Theoretically, you can setup a db on a safely sandboxed server, pass in Request, get the result, and then mysql_escape the response before use:

```
$str = '\100Bobby \"Tables \n';
mysql_query("UPDATE parse SET str = '$str' WHERE id='0'");
$out = mysql_query("SELECT str FROM parse WHERE id='0'");
//echo array_pop(mysql_fetch_array($out));  echoes @Bobby "Tables

$out = mysql_real_escape_string(array_pop(mysql_fetch_array($out)));
mysql_query("...")// Using the correct yet safe string
```

More practically, this means that if there was some way to turn a string into a mysql resource, it would be a safe an effective way of converting a single-quoted string to a double-quoted string.

Unfortunately, the fine folks at PHP say "[converting to a resource makes no sense.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php)"
Perhaps someone knows a hack?